# include other content type post ID not working

Tags: posts

I am calling content type  portfolio in a page but i want to show some pages by id with portfolio content type, below code only retrieve  the portfolio posts.

```
     $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'include' => '73,71' , 
    'posts_per_page' => 30, 'order' => 'ASC', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'));
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Note: include Id 73,71 content types are 'page'

Answer (score 0):

try adding page like this on post type `'post_type' => array( 'portfolio', 'page' )`

`post_type` can accept array... more of it here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: i've already try but its also return more pages like contact-us, about-us that i don't want, i just call pages by id of 73,71.